# OIM _Oracle identity manager _ email addition

Tags: email, addition, oim

OIM _oracle identity manager when all the jobs run user will be provisioned to oim as well as OID.  After user creation welcome email automatically send to the user. Some of the users like manager role only have the mail id. All other users welcome mail send to their manager. The managers will share the details to the users.

Now my requirement is the welcome email need to be copied to one of the default mail id. Could you please suggest me something. It's a task provided from my client. I need the help from OIM support side

Comment: are you using OOTB email template?